# fitbounds to cover all available markers google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've used `map.fitbounds` to zoom and center the map to show available markers.Here is my code,

```
 marker = new google.maps.Marker(
 {
  map:map,
  draggable:true,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  icon: icon
 });

 marker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
 {
 map:map,
 draggable:true,
 animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
 icon:icon
 });

 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 var markers = [marker, marker2];
 for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
 position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);

 bounds.extend(position)
 }
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

But the above code doesn't works.How may I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

try this. i think u used wrong variable in bounds.extend()...this code is worked for me

```
var createMarker = function (info){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.latitude, info.longitude),
            map: $scope.map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,


        });
        loc = new google.maps.LatLng(info.latitude, info.longitude);
        bounds.extend(loc);

    }  
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        createMarker(markers[i]);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Thanks for code.Here is my updated code,`var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 var markers = [marker, marker2];

var createMarker = function (info){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.latitude, info.longitude),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,


        });
        loc = new google.maps.LatLng(info.latitude, info.longitude);
        bounds.extend(loc);

    }  
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        createMarker(markers[i]);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);`